# Definition of chaos for a bounded orbit

Tags: symplectic-geometry, chaos-theory, integrable-systems

Let $\rho : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{2n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ be a hamiltonian flow, *i.e.* a 1-parameter family of symplectomorphisms with respect to $t$ obtained from integrating a hamiltonian vector field $X_H$ for which

$$ \imath_{X_H} \omega = dH ,$$

$\omega$ being the canonical 2-form over $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and $H \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$. There are several definitions of chaos using measure theory, ergodicity, mixing, etc, but I would like a definition that is applicable to the *orbit*, not the system. This is usually done somewhat formally through Lyapunov exponents and affirmations such as "the classical orbits separate exponentially fast". This does not appear to be true in a chaotic sea bounded above and below by non-resonant KAM tori in a scenario of mixed phase space, since trajectories cannot separate for distances larger than the outer torus' diameter.

I was thinking about something like: If an orbit is regular there is an infinite number of $t$-values such that $\rho(t_1, x) = \rho(t_2, x) = \dots $, since the flow is periodic. It the orbit is chaotic, then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $| \rho (t,x) - \rho(t',x)| > \epsilon$, so the orbit is not periodic. Since orbits that are not periodic are not symplectomorphic to a torus, the orbit is chaotic. Does this make any sense as a definition of a chaotic orbit?

Comment: First, your last paragraph seems contradictory: are the orbit and/or the flow periodic or not? This makes your question ambiguous and hence difficult to answer. Second, the "exponential divergence" sometimes used to define chaotic systems is a condition for the linearization of the dynamics along orbits, hence it can make sense even in a bounded region. However, Hamiltonian systems preserve volumes, so if they are "divergent" in some transverse direction to an orbit, then they are "convergent" in some other direction and therefore never chaotic in the above sense.

Comment: @JordanPayette Chaotic orbits are not periodic. That's what I meant to say in the last paragraph: If it is periodic, it's not chaotic. Regarding your last statement: Are you implying that hamiltonian systems cannot have positive Lyapunov exponents? Because that's not true.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your paragraph: if the *flow* is periodic, then *every* orbit is periodic, hence *none* is chaotic (assuming there is a meaning to an orbit being chaotic). No, I'm not implying that a Hamiltonian system can't have positive Lyapunov exponents, but rather that they can't all be positive, so that "not all classical orbits separate exponentially fast". On a different matter, what conditions would you put on $t$ and $t'$ in your last paragraph? If the dynamics occurs in a bounded region, Poincaré recurrence theorem might prevent your definition from being meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but it sounds like you might be interested in *symbolic dynamics* where you divide up the phase space and show that there are orbits visting all states, which is one of the hallmarks of chaos in Hamiltonian systens. The [horseshoe map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_map#Orbits)  possesses such dynamics and "looking for chaos" in Hamiltonian systems is often a euphemism for "looking for horseshoes."